# HTTP Get Method

Tags: http

I am using HTTP Get method to call Rest API but I am getting error 401 i.e. unauthorized. so the problem is Rest API uses NTLM Authentication I want to send the credentials through Header of Get Method so my question is, is it possible to send NTLM authentication details send through header and if yes then how?

Thanks,
Nitin

Comment: Using Java? Python, .Net? Some code?

Comment: Hi, I am using WiztoolsRestcient tool for calling API, where we can add header values.

Comment: sorry its NTLM not RTLM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I got it. we can use the NTLM Authentication by passing values through header and the values are like below,

user-name : uname
password : *******
ntlm-authentication : true

Regards,
Nitin